# how can i modify a field in mongodb which is of array type using nodejs code

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have to modify an array field in mongoDB, using nodejs code. I am getting error when adding for loop in update fields, how can I do modify of array. gefencing is a function which wil return a array which have geo coordinate values. I would like to update this arry in mongodb. how can I do..can someone help me

```
var filter = { 
          _id : Id
        };

var updateFields = {
name : newName,
for(var j = 0; j<getGeoFencing(geoFencing).length; j++){
        var latvalue = getGeoFencing(geoFencing)[j].latitude;
        var lngvalue = getGeoFencing(geoFencing)[j].longitude;
        zone.geofencing[j] = { latitude: latvalue, longitude: lngvalue }
      }
} 
Rooms.findOneAndUpdate(filter,updateFields,(err,res)=>{
      if(res !=null){
       console.log('updation sucess') 


}
```

Comment: Your for loop should not be in your variable assignment for starters. You need to create the variables before you add them to your dictionary.

Comment: could you please share some reference

Comment: what does `getGeoFencing` do?

Comment: it is returning array which have lat and long values